# jqgrid data is reordering automatically , in collapsegrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

when I am providing the dataobject to the jqgrid its getting reshuffled , not able to identify the cause, please see the `working fiddlle` [fiddle jqgrid](http://jsfiddle.net/vikas_pachori/47g5pLv4/)

the rows are not displaying in the order they are supplied, any help will be really appreciated.
Required out put is that all data should come in the order provided, please refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vikas_pachori/47g5pLv4/)
for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand your requirements. I suppose that you should replace the options

```js
"groupText":["getGrouptext"]
"datatype":"local"
"data":[...]
```

to

```js
"groupText":["{0}"]
"datatype":"jsonstring"
"datastr":[...]
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/47g5pLv4/2/

Comment: the reshuffling of the data is happening only when $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid") is called after the creating of the grid. Please see the `updated` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vikas_pachori/47g5pLv4/3/)

Comment: @Vikas: I think that you don't understand the reason of changing the order of rows. One *have to* order the data by `grouping_expand` if you use `"groupField":["grouping_expand"]`. If you use `"datatype":"jsonstring"` then jqGrid skips **initial** sorting and suppose that the data are already sorted. On the next reloading the data will be sorted because `"datatype":"jsonstring"` is already changed to `"datatype":"local"`. You can reset `datatype` from `"local"` back to `"jsonstring"` to prevent sorting. The best way would be to specify `sorttype` callbacks, which sorts the data like you need.

Comment: this is helpful , as you mentioned _n the next reloading the data will be sorted because "datatype":"jsonstring" is already changed to "datatype":"local". You can reset datatype from "local" back to "jsonstring" to prevent sorting_. How to achieve that as the trigger calls the method `reloadGrid`, so should I make the changes in the src or is there any other way , thanks in adavance .

Comment: @Vikas: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand your last question because you don't describes your scenario exactly. Who triggers `reloadGrid`? Do you trigger it directly in your code? **Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid?** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Additionally I suppose that you use jqGrid in a little strange form. If you would use jqGrid in the standard way then you will don't have any problem at all.

Comment: jqGrid  4.6.0 - jQuery Grid freeJqgrid , and I am programmatically calling the reload as I did in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vikas_pachori/47g5pLv4/3/) fidde

Comment: @Vikas: Sorry, but calling of `$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid")` directly after creating of the grid has really no sense. You can call for example `$("#grid").remove()` to destroy previously created results. If you need for example replace the data and then trigger reload grid that you should just reset `datatype`: `$("#grid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype:"jsonstring"}).trigger("reloadGrid");` see http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/47g5pLv4/4/

Comment: @Vikas: ["free jqGrid"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is the product name of the fork of jqGrid, which I develop. The product "jqGrid" is dead. After version 4.7 (in the version 4.7.1) Tony Tomov changed the license agreement of jqGrid, renamed it to "Guriddo jqGrid JS" (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)) and made it **commercial**. See the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Thus "jqGrid" exists till version 4.7 and it's dead now. "free jqGrid" in version 4.14.0 and "Guriddo jqGrid JS" in version 5.2.1 will be developed and supported.